# find a list in an other list

Tags: common-lisp

I have a file which name is `dictionary.lisp`. That includes some words like

```
(defparameter *dictionary* '(
                    (a b a)
                    (a b a d i)
.
.
)
```

I try to find them as a list. I tried the followings

```
[5]> (find '((a b a d i)) *dictionary* :test 'equal  )
NIL
[6]> (find '((a b a d i)) *dictionary* :test #'equalp  )
NIL
[7]> (member '((a b a d i)) *dictionary* :test 'equal  )
NIL
[8]> (member '((a b a d i)) *dictionary* :test #'equalp  )
NIL
[9]> (find '((a b a d i)) *dictionary* :test #'subsetp  )
NIL
```

Is there any lisp function that can return non-nil?

Comment: You're searching for the wrong thing.  Don't `(find '((a b a d i)) ...)`, do `(find '(a b a d i) ...)` with an equal or equalp test (which you're doing correctly in your first four examples).

Comment: what is your advice? how can I get the expected result? @JoshuaTaylor

Comment: I think I wrote it pretty clearly in that comment.  There's a different between the list (a b a d i), which is a list of five symbols, and ((a b a d i)) which is a list of one list containing five symbols.  Your dictionary contains (a b a d i), but it doesn't contain ((a b a d i)).  I've shown a proper example in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **equal** or **equalp** as your test, which you're doing in four of your examples.  You also need to search for something that's actually in the list.  For instance, The dictionary you've described contains the list of five symbols **(a b a d i)** as an element, but *not* the list **((a b a d i))** (which is a list containing a single element, and that element is a list of five symbols).  This means you'd do **(find '(a b a d i) … :test 'equal)**:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *dictionary* '((a b a)
                                      (a b a d i)))
*DICTIONARY*
CL-USER> (find '((a b a d i)) *dictionary* :test 'equal)
NIL
CL-USER> (find '(a b a d i) *dictionary* :test 'equal)
(A B A D I)
CL-USER> (find '(f o o) *dictionary* :test 'equal)
NIL
```

Comment: I have tested it of course my aim is to find like that  ((a b a d i)) but thank you for your help

Comment: @hax well, find compares the item with theach elements in the list. You could add `:key 'list`,and get the results that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 25 > (defparameter *dictionary* '((a b a) (a b a d i)))
*DICTIONARY*

CL-USER 26 > (defun my-find (list0 list1)
               (and (find (first list0) list1 :test #'equal)
                    t))
MY-FIND

CL-USER 27 > (my-find '((a b a d i)) *dictionary*)
T
```

It just does not look like it will make much sense.